# Suspecious hidden .swp file in usr/bin

Tags: vim

after I ran rkhunter it showed suspected hidden file /usr/bin/.piny.py.swp. After a little google I came to know that it is made by VIM. But at that time VIM was not installed in my system. Well I ran vim -r .piny.py.swp
and the result looks something like this:
/usr/bin/piny.py^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^MU3210^@^@^@^@#"! ^S^RU^@^@... continued.
How can I see what all is this. Is there anything to worry.

Edit 1:
Does .piny.py exist?               Yes
didn't exit normally?               Yes it did not exit normally. I have to press CTRL + Z to exit

Further there was a line of   "".piny.py" [noeol][converted] 1L, 12297C"  at the end of file vi piny.py and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31845/418682) posts says:   "especially including the last line. If there is no end-of-line (eol) on the last line, then it is an unusual situation and the file most certainly was not created by a standard UNIX editor."

Comment: Using `^Z` simply suspends `vi` (so you can `bg` or `cont`inue it). Exit `vi` with `ZZ`, `:wq`, `:q`, or even `:q!`.

Answer (score 1):

The `swp` file can be created by `vi` as well. Someone (check the ownership and times) did `vi .piny.py`, and didn't exit normally.  Does `.piny.py` exist? That might be a concern, otherwise just delete `.pliny.py.swp`

Read `man vi ex`.  Use of the `.swp` file is usually

```
vi -r.piny.py.swp .piny.py
#
# or, using the default behavior
vi -r .pliny.py
```

to recover `.piny.py`. `.swp` files are meant for `vi`, not for humans.

Using `^Z` simply suspends `vi` (so you can `bg` or `cont`inue it). Exit `vi` with `ZZ`, `:wq`, `:q`, or even `:q!`.

Comment: Waltinator I have edited the question and added output.